# Why socket.on("reconnect") doesn't work, when I reload page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have following code on client:

```
socket.on('reconnect', function() {
    alert("Reconnected!");
});
```

Documentation says:

*Event: 'reconnect'
Fired upon a successful reconnection.*

But I have `alert` message only when I am rebooting my server. What sould I do, to handle user reconnection (or page refresh) with `socket.on('reconnect');`

Comment: `connect` and `reconnect` are different things. When you reload the page, you're not "reconnecting". You are "connecting".

Comment: @Marquizzo So what is reconnect in socket.io? Where I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you need to bind to is [`connect`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#event-connect), which fires upon:

1. A successful first connection (such as a page reload) or
2. A reconnection (for example, when you lose WiFi signal, and then gain it again).

The [`reconnect`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#event-reconnect) event fires only when you lose connection and then re-gain it while in the same session. It does not fire when you first load the page.